# .NET Core Identity after successful login go back to login page

Tags: angular, authentication, asp.net-core-mvc, identityserver4

I have application in .NET Core MVC. Authentication is did in Identity and rest of the application is in the Angular.
Login page is in `Areas.Identity.Pages.Account.Login.cshtml`

I have read that `app.UseMvc()` have to be after `app.UseAuthentication()`
This is my `Startup.cs` file:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    var keysFolder = Path.Combine(WebHostEnvironment.ContentRootPath, "temp-keys");

    services.AddDataProtection()
        .SetApplicationName("MyApp")
        .PersistKeysToFileSystem(new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(keysFolder))
        .SetDefaultKeyLifetime(TimeSpan.FromDays(14));

    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(
            Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyAppConnection")));
            
            
    services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddCookie(options =>
        {
            options.LoginPath = "/Home/Login";
        });

    services.AddMvc().AddMvcOptions(Mvcoption => {
        Mvcoption.EnableEndpointRouting = false;
    });

    services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

    services.AddIdentityServer()
        .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>();

    services.AddAuthentication()
        .AddIdentityServerJwt();

    services.AddControllersWithViews();
    services.AddRazorPages();
    // In production, the Angular files will be served from this directory
    services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
    {
        configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist";
    });

    services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(Configuration);
...

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    loggerFactory.AddFile("Logs/mylog-{Date}.txt");

    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
        // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();

    if (!env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseSpaStaticFiles();
    }

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseMvc();
    app.UseIdentityServer();
    app.UseAuthorization();
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "default",
            pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        endpoints.MapRazorPages();
    });

    app.UseSpa(spa =>
    {
        // To learn more about options for serving an Angular SPA from ASP.NET Core,
        // see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=864501

        spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
        }
    });
}
```

When I run application in my Visual Studio I can login without any problem. But when I publish application on the server I can't. After successful login application go back to the login page.
Logs for login action on my server:

```
2020-07-16T16:29:06.9806220+00:00 800004b4-0000-be00-b63f-84710c7967bb [INF] User logged in. (fdce0db4)
2020-07-16T16:29:07.1073699+00:00 800004b5-0000-be00-b63f-84710c7967bb [INF] Invoking IdentityServer endpoint: "IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeCallbackEndpoint" for "/connect/authorize/callback" (f7642de5)
2020-07-16T16:29:07.1086131+00:00 800004b5-0000-be00-b63f-84710c7967bb [INF] Showing login: User is not authenticated (4b8d50b2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a good practice is to not mix IdentityServer with your SPA application, I think its better to keep them separate. When you follow the separation of concerns principles then is that troubleshooting is easier.

I would also place

```
app.UseAuthorization();
```

Directly after

```
app.UseAuthentication();
```

You should not use appUseMvc() and UseEndpoints() at the same time. Remove UseMVC(). See this document [Migrate from ASP.NET Core 2.2 to 3.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio#mvc-service-registration)

Comment: Ok, I tried your tips, but without result. But thanks for help, I removed IdentityServer from y project

Comment: I think you have multiple issues in your setup of the ASP.NET Core request pipeline, its important to get it right.